# Undefined reference when use c-function from c++ file

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, stm32

I just begin new project in eclipse. Try to use C-library from C++ file.
In headers, where are prototypes of functions, here is:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif

// prototypes...
void Init_Configuration(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

It's initialize.h. In main.cpp i include this file and try use function:

```
#include "initialize.h"

int main()
{
    Init_Configuration();

    // Life cycle
    while (1)
    {

    }
}
```

After compilation i get this error:

> initialize.c:54: undefined reference to `SPI_Cmd'

In source C file "initialize.c", where i also include "initialize.h" i  use function from C-library for stm32f2xx:

```
#include "initialize.h"
#include "stm32f2xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f2xx_spi.h"
#include "stm32f2xx_gpio.h"

// some code
SPI_Cmd(SPI1, DISABLE);
// some code
```

In this library also is this code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif
...
```

I don't know where a problem. Please, help!

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling initialize.c? You need to do that as well as including the header.

Comment: @jignatius, yes, i sure. And I included the headers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Presumably you need to link to the `stm32f2xx` library

Comment: @AlanBirtles, in the sense of connecting to a file through include?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, In additional, I connected the library stm32f2xx.h. Did not help

Comment: Read the linked question and learn how to link libraries